# Geometric realization of function complexes of simplicial sets

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\operatorname{sSet}$ be the category of simplicial sets and $\operatorname{Top}$ the category of (say, compactly generated) topological spaces. There is a pair of adjoint functors called geometric realization and singular set:

$$
|\cdot |:\operatorname{sSet}\to \operatorname{Top}:S_\bullet 
$$

I am aware of some of the basic properties of this, but I am confused about the way it acts on function complexes, as I will explain.

Given two simplicail sets $X,Y$ we can form the *simplicial set* of maps between them, which we call the function complex and it is defined by
$$
\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)_n = \operatorname{Hom}(\Delta^n \times X,Y)
$$

with the obvious face/degeneracy maps. This serves as an "internal hom" functor and it turns $\operatorname{sSet}$ into a cartesian closed category. In $\operatorname{Top}$ we also have an internal hom by endowing the set of maps between two topological spaces with the compact open topology. The general rather vague question is

> What is the relationship between the space $|\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)|$ and $\operatorname{Map}(|X|,|Y|)$?

If I didn't make a mistake, I have the following. There is always a canonical map
$$
\phi:|\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)|\to \operatorname{Map}(|X|,|Y|)
$$
which is adjoint to a map$$
\psi:\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)\to S_{\bullet}(\operatorname{Map}(|X|,|Y|))
$$

and we have a natural isomorphism
$$
S_{\bullet}(\operatorname{Map}(|X|,|Y|))\simeq \operatorname{Map}(X,S_\bullet|Y|)
$$

The composition with $\psi$ is the map induced from the unit of the adjunction $Y\to S_\bullet|Y|$ which is a weak equivalence. Hence, I suspect that if $Y$ is a Kan complex then $\psi$, and hence $\phi$, is a weak equivalnce, but I lack the precise argument.

I do not expect $\phi$ to be weak homotopy equivalence in general, but I would like to know what can be said about it in this generality. For example, is $\phi$ injective on $\pi_0$? is it a cofibration?

It all seems very standard and well known, but I find it difficult to extract the answers from the standard sources like Goerss-Jardine for example.

Comment: I am inclined to agree that you have a weak equivalence if $Y$ is a Kan complex. You need to use the fact that the standard model structure is compatible with exponential objects.

Comment: [Schwede](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/SymSpec-v3.pdf) theorem A.3.2 asserts your suspicion, though he doesn't really give either references or proofs.

Answer (score 5):

For brevity I will write $[-, -]$ for exponential objects.

First things first: the comparison map
$\newcommand{\rn}[1]{\left|{#1}\right|}$
$$\phi : \rn{[X, Y]} \to [\rn{X}, \rn{Y}]$$
is more easily described as the transpose of the map
$$\rn{[X, Y]} \times \rn{X} \cong \rn{[X, Y] \times X} \to \rn{Y}$$
obtained by applying geometric realisation to the evaluation morphism $[X, Y] \times X \to Y$. (In particular, we need the fact that $\rn{-}$ preserves binary products.)

As you suspect, $\phi : \rn{[X, Y]} \to [\rn{X}, \rn{Y}]$ can fail to be a weak homotopy equivalence. For example, we may take $X$ to be $\{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$ considered as a discrete simplicial set and $Y$ to be the simplicial set corresponding to the following directed graph (not category!):
$$0 \to 1 \to 2 \to 3 \to \cdots$$
Clearly, $Y$ is connected. On the other hand, $[X, Y]$ is not: there is no path from the vertex $(0, 0, 0, \ldots)$ to $(0, 1, 2, \ldots)$. Thus $\phi : \rn{[X, Y]} \to [\rn{X}, \rn{Y}]$ even fails to be injective in $\pi_0$.

Also, as you suspect, $\phi : \rn{[X, Y]} \to [\rn{X}, \rn{Y}]$ is a weak homotopy equivalence if $Y$ is a Kan complex. It suffices to verify that $S \phi : S \rn{[X, Y]} \to S [\rn{X}, \rn{Y}]$ is a weak homotopy equivalence. There is a natural isomorphism $S [\rn{X}, T] \to [X, S T]$ and you can check that the composite 
$$[X, Y] \to S \rn{[X, Y]} \to S [\rn{X}, \rn{Y}] \to [X, S \rn{Y}]$$
is induced by the unit $Y \to S \rn{Y}$. But $[X, -]$ preserves simplicial homotopy equivalences, and $[X, Y] \to S \rn{[X, Y]}$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, so if $Y \to S \rn{Y}$ is a simplicial homotopy equivalence, then $S \phi : S \rn{[X, Y]} \to S [\rn{X}, \rn{Y}]$ is a weak homotopy equivalence as desired; in particular, this is true when $Y$ is a Kan complex.